# In mongoDB how can I change a field name of a object, and have my change stream recognize the change?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, changestream

So far I've tried a few things such as this:

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, {$rename: {"audit":"audit1"}})
```

I've noticed that my change stream isn't processessing the change. This is the command that set the change stream initially:

```
db.adminCommand({modifyChangeStreams: 1, database: "db", collection: "collection", enable: true});
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be great.
thanks

Comment: Ideally I would like any changes to the collections (objects, new records, etc) to be reflected in the changestream.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the "_change stream isn't processessing the change_"?

Comment: I guess I should mention that I have a kafka topic that picks up changes and inserts them into my data warehouse. But the changestream doesn't seem to recoginize any changes currently.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like DocumentDB. There is no such command "modifyChangeStreams" in MongoDB. In MongoDB you open change stream  like this

```
c = db.collection.watch(); 
c.tryNext();
```

Comment: correct, looks like I am using documentdb.